# SQL выборка по кванту значений

Tags: php, mysql

Встал вопрос выборки данных по квантам значений. Объясню ситуацию:

Есть таблица payment(платежи):

```
id_user [int]
sum     [int]
date    [date]
```

sum (сумма) может быть относительно любой от 0 и до 100000 например.

Нужно сгруппировать вывод данных по сумме с квантом в 50 монет.

Например:

```
0-49 монет - заплатили  14 пользователей.
50-99 монет - 59 пользователей
100-150 - 147
и т.д. до конца (до 100000)
```

Надеюсь, изъяснил все понятно. По-другому никак не могу сформулировать поставленную задачу. У кого есть какие предложения?

Нужно сформировать SQL-запрос *(в крайнем случае использовать php)*

Comment: Почему здесь <br /> не заменяются на перевод строки!?

Comment: Пользователи, которые заплатили 50 монет, попадают в две категории?

Можно сделать дополнительное вычисляемое поле (например делением на 50). Тогда по нему можно будет легко сгруппировать. А собственно вывод уже дошлифовать в php.

Comment: В одну. Неправильно указал,сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Примерно так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f97e6/5/0):

```
select 
    count(id_user),
    concat_ws("...", floor(sum/50)*50, (floor(sum/50)+1)*50-1) as interva_l
from payment
    group by floor(sum/50);
```

Группируем по дополнительному вычисляемому полю (делением на 50)

Comment: Огромаднейшее спасибо )